# How to extract data from this code (never seen this format before)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin in my wordpress that stores my data in a specific way. I have a problem on how to extract that data into an array using php. The data currently saved in database is in this kind of format which i have never seen before. I want to get the name, price and the referral amount from this data.

I have tried using php foreach looping to extract data but it wont recognize the foreach function.

```
a:2:{i:0;a:4:s:4:"name";s:14:"Tower";s:2:"id";i:4177;s:5:"price";i:500;s:15:"referral_amount";s:3:"20";}i:1;a:4:s:4:"name";s:25:"Square";s:2:"id";i:3998;s:5:"price";i:178;s:15:"referral_amount";s:4:"87.4";}}
```

I wanted the array to store the data in this kind of way:

```
{
  name:'Tower',
  price:500,
  referral_amount:20,
}
```

Does anyone knew how to extract this kind of data using php?

Comment: What database is used?

Comment: The string that you have posted seems like a serialized string, but there must be any typo or you might not have copied it OK as by some proves i did it is not being parsed.
You can try to use the php function unserialize.

Comment: this looks like a serialized string - You can normally use `unserialize()` to get it back - but it looks like there is something wrong with the string given?

Comment: You can also test it here : https://www.unserialize.com

Comment: thank u leli,stender.. yes..i just check it on unserialize.com..apparently it is a serialized string...it is the first time i encounter this data format..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = 'a:2:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:14:"Tower";s:2:"id";i:4177;s:5:"price";i:500;s:15:"referral_amount";s:3:"20";}i:1;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:25:"Square";s:2:"id";i:3998;s:5:"price";i:178;s:15:"referral_amount";s:4:"87.4";}}';
$data = preg_replace_callback('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!',
function ($match) {
    return 's:'.strlen($match[2]).':"'.$match[2].'";';
},
$data);
$data_array = unserialize($data);
$final_data = json_encode($data_array);

echo $final_data;
```

Comment: May be this can helps.Please try this.

Comment: Watch out for that `/e` modifier, its not available in PHP7.3

Comment: I have fix this issue. Pls try now.